# Filter objects out of an array in JS

Tags: javascript, array

I have an array of objects `arr`. One object looks like this:

```
obj = {
  name: 'name'
  email: 'email'
}
```

And then I have an array with strings (emails)

```
var excludedEmails = ['email1','email2',...]
```

I want to filter the excluded emails out of the `arr`.

Is there a better/faster way than this in VanillaJS (I am assuming the strings in `excludedEmails` are all upper case:

```
var filteredPersons = []
arr.forEach(function(person){
      if(!excludedEmails.includes(person.email.toUpperCase())){
        filteredPersons.push(person);
      }
})
```

Comment: That looks like example code. And sure, it's called [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function that takes a predicate to filter by. It's funny that your question mentions the filter word which happens to be the name of the function.

Here's an example of usage:

```
var filteredPersons =
  arr.filter(person => !excludedEmails.includes(person.email.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: note that ie 11 doesn't support arrow functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why

Answer (score 2):

The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function is what you're looking for. Here's an example given on the documentation page that should demonstrate exactly how it's used:

```
var words = ["spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present"];

var longWords = words.filter(function(word){
  return word.length > 6;
});

// Filtered array longWords is ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

Additionally, the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function can be useful to iterate through arrays to apply a function to each value in the array instead of just filtering out values based on a bool result (in your case, whether the email is in excluded emails). For a basic check to see if the email address is excluded, you'll want filter. If you do any processing on the emails array (say, sending emails), you may want to look into map.